# Associating WinRT DeviceInformation objects with WMI objects (Win32_PnPEntity)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, wmi

The Windows.Devices.Enumeration namespace has functionality for watching device arrivals and utilizes the DeviceInformation class in the event callback to expose information about which device has arrived.

The DeviceInformation class exposes some properties of the device interface detected, including an 'Id' property which is supposedly the System.Devices.DeviceInstanceId property, which is described as 'The identity of the device. This is also the value of DeviceInformation.Id.'

I expected this value to be a Device Instance Id, as that is what it is named. However, it does not seem to conform to the same format or include the same information as other Device Instance ID's elsewhere on Windows.

The device I am capturing is a removable disk drive over SCSI, plugged in via thunderbolt. When utilizing WMI to capture Win32_PnPEntity classes corresponding to the disk PNP entity, it's device ID does not resemble the System.Devices.DeviceInstanceId from the WinRT API.

My application requires me to be able to correlate the device received from the WinRT API with the equivalent device in WMI. I am aware that you can process device arrivals with a WMI callback as well, however that is not appropriate for the context of the code used in device arrivals versus what is consuming them.

I am looking for a direct way to go from the DeviceInformation object received to a concrete WMI object. I am hoping that I will not have to iterate over all WMI objects but that may also be an acceptable solution if it's necessary.

I can update with more details and clarification if this is not clear.

Comment: I use this Device Explorer open source tool I wrote (https://github.com/smourier/DeviceExplorer) to output WinRT information vs a WMI Explorer tool and I see the exact same values for both https://i.imgur.com/Q9LROqY.png

Comment: In the DeviceInformation.Properties (Dictionary), the Hardware IDs (`System.Devices.HardwareIds`) should be like `PCI\VEN_XXXX&DEV_XXXX&SUBSYS_XXXXXXXX&REV_XX`,which should look familiar

Comment: @SimonMourier very interesting, it is not the case on my system. The device I am processing is through SCSI with an HBA controller through a thunderbolt port. I am wondering if this is hardware specific behavior.

Comment: You mean there's a match in general (like in my screenshot) but it doesn't match for one device? Are you sure you're looking at the same device, that's a common trap.

Comment: The format in general is completely different. I have not tried multiple device types. I am using the DevieWatcher with the filter for removable storage. Unfortunately, I don't have direct access to the hardware that I am using right now but I will be able to provide more details soon. Given that it seems to be the case that they should match, I will have to do a thorough check on my own end to make sure I'm not making a silly error.

Comment: I wanted to give an update on this: I was looking at the wrong class of devices (Volumes instead of the physical disks themselves). 

It is deceptively easy to accidentally be looking at the wrong device, especially if you don't use an AQS filter and instead rely on the DeviceClass filtering option in DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher.

Simon, if you make an answer suggesting they should be the same, I will accept it as answered.

Comment: Well, there's no real value added here apart from being the itching powder, you should answer yourself :-)